# How can I know the state change with ethereum's transaction?

Tags: state, ethereum

Like [the link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x14752b822c5ada055d6b9fc5febe4255c23069b1cbb50ab490c184ab448ff1b0#statechange) in Etherscan, it shows before and after balance change of eth or token by address through the transaction.
How does Etherscan create this kind of data?

How do you find data about this before and after balance in the Ethereum node??
Is there an API known from json-rpc api?
Is there a way to know through [transaction receipt](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_gettransactionreceipt)?

I know there is an 'eth_getbalance' function, but I don't think I can know the before and after of the token through this function.

Please tell me how can I track balance change by the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> Like the link in Etherscan, it shows before and after balance change of eth or token by address through the transaction. How does Etherscan create this kind of data?

You need to use [trace_transaction](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/trace_transaction) API for ETH changes.

For token balances changes you need to parse logs of transaction receipt for ERC-20 transfer events.

Comment: Is it possible to check the ETH before and after balance amount of the address in the trace data?
The value seems to show only the ETH value that is being transferred. What value can you tell by looking at it?

  ERC-20 transfer events can also be known before and after, not just the amount transferred??

I'm curious how to analyze it.

Or do I need to know the balance value of ETH & Token of all addresses in advance?

Comment: If you have archive node, you can also do `eth_getBalance` call on before and after target block number. However doing this for large number of accounts is impractical.

Comment: I am of the same opinion. You cannot call `eth_getBalance` every time. So, it seems that the [Statechange](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x14752b822c5ada055d6b9fc5febe4255c23069b1cbb50ab490c184ab448ff1b0#statechange) data displayed by Etherscan must have used a different method... I didn't know how, so I asked!

Comment: Etherscan is using traces